# How avoid duplicate props in Material UI? React JS.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I created form based on components from Material-UI. I want to control `state` of my inputs from parent component like below, but I have an error "No duplicate props allowed". Yup, it makes sense for me - I have 3 times `onChange` parameters. I'm curious is it possible to solve it or I need to completely arrange the code?

Parent component

```
handleSubmitTask = (e) =>{
  alert()
 });
}

handleTextFieldChange = (event) =>{
  this.setState({
  nameTask: event.target.value,  
 });
}

handleCloseEditDialog = () => {
  this.setState({openEdit: false});
}

handleChangeDate = (event, date) => {
  this.setState({
  deadline: date
});
}

handleChangeSelectField = (event, index, priority) => {
 this.setState(
   {priority}
 );
}

render() {
 const actionsEdit = [
  <FlatButton label="Edit" primary={true} keyboardFocused={true} onClick={e => this.handleSubmitTask(e)} />,
  <FlatButton label="Cancel" primary={true} onClick={this.handleCloseEditDialog} />
]; 

return (
  <div>
    <EditTaskDialog open={this.state.openEdit} actions={actionsEdit} 
    nameTask={this.state.nameTask} priority={this.state.priority} deadline={this.state.deadline}
    onChange={e => this.handleTextFieldChange(e)} onChange={this.handleChangeDate} onChange={this.handleChangeSelectField}
    />
  </div>
);
}}

export default Home;
```

Child component:

```
render() {
  return (
   <form>
    <Dialog title="Edit your Task" open={this.props.open} actions={this.props.actions}>
      <TextField floatingLabelText="Task" value={this.props.nameTask} errorText={this.state.nameTaskError}
      onChange={this.props.onChangeText} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
      <DatePicker floatingLabelText="Deadline" value={this.props.deadline} onChange={this.props.onChangeDate} />
      <SelectField floatingLabelText="Priority" value={this.props.priority} onChange={this.props.onChangeSelect}>
          <MenuItem value="High" primaryText="High" />
          <MenuItem value="Medium" primaryText="Medium" />
          <MenuItem value="Low" primaryText="Low" />
      </SelectField>
    </Dialog>  
  </form>
);}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to expand on @dangling-cruze's answer.

While you could create a function like...

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.handleTextFieldChange(e);
  this.handleChangeDate();
  this.handleChangeSelectField();
}
```

... this would execute all 3 functions and will yield the functionality you want, however, because of how each of those functions are defined you are also doing `setState()` three times, which is not optimal.

Instead, why not just implement all that functionality in one function? Like so:

```
handleChange(event, index, date, priority) {
  let obj = {};
  if(date !== this.state.deadline) {
    obj.deadline = date;
  }
  if(event.target.value !== this.state.nameTask) {
    obj.nameTask = event.target.value;
  }
  if(priority !== this.state.priority) {
    obj.priority = priority;
  }
  this.setState(obj);
}
```

This will do everything you want, in *one* `setState()` call.

Comment: Totally! I was going to edit that next, but since you already did.. Kudos :)

Comment: @DanglingCruze, thanks. Just make sure the parameters come in in the right order. If this solved your question, please consider marking it as "accepted". Good luck.

Comment: It makes sense but didn't resolve my problem. When I typing in the text field I changing rest of my inputs (datePicker and Select), because state is set to every input when function is calling. It causes errors.

Comment: @Italik, add some if-cases inside the function and determine which part of the state you want to update. For example, if the input date is different to what was previously stored in state, update it and otherwise don't.

Comment: @Italik, I edited the question. It might not be a ready copy-paste solution, but I think this should help you get going with the rest of the implementation. I never used MaterialUI, so I don't know the ins and outs of it, but I assume only one event can trigger at a time? If so, you don't need to use `obj`  and can just do `setState()` directly inside each `if` and also use `else if`. The implementation I added above "builds" an object that is then set as the new state and is only really useful if multiple events can change at any one time.

Comment: Just an update. Calling `setState` multiple times isn't really inefficient. React batches the multiple calls to `setState` and merges it to avoid the reconciliation thrice in this case.

Comment: @DanglingCruze, in this context, yes you are right because it happens in an event handler. In other contexts however, that might not happen. So while you are technically correct here, it is probably best to use whatever method *always* works. I consider it best practice to always call `setState()` no more than once. Besides, it also makes your code more readable... You make a valid point though.

Answer (score 1):

In Parent component, at this line:

```
<EditTaskDialog open={this.state.openEdit} actions={actionsEdit} 
nameTask={this.state.nameTask} priority={this.state.priority} deadline={this.state.deadline}
onChange={e => this.handleTextFieldChange(e)} onChange={this.handleChangeDate} onChange={this.handleChangeSelectField}
/>
```

You have defined `onChange` 3 times.

The solution is to create a method that will call these three handlers for you and use that method for `onChange`.

I hope that helps.

EDIT:

```
<EditTaskDialog open={this.state.openEdit} actions={actionsEdit} 
nameTask={this.state.nameTask} priority={this.state.priority} deadline={this.state.deadline} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

and then define a method in the component:

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.handleTextFieldChange(e);
  this.handleChangeDate();
  this.handleChangeSelectField();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have defined three times. The question is how to create that method and call handlers?

Comment: Updated in answer. And don't forget to bind this to the method in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<EditTaskDialog open={this.state.openEdit} actions={actionsEdit} 
nameTask={this.state.nameTask} priority={this.state.priority} deadline={this.state.deadline}
onChange={e => this.handleTextFieldChange(e)} onChange={this.handleChangeDate} onChange={this.handleChangeSelectField}
/>
```

to this

```
<EditTaskDialog open={this.state.openEdit} actions={actionsEdit} 
nameTask={this.state.nameTask} priority={this.state.priority} deadline={this.state.deadline}
onChange={e => {this.handleTextFieldChange(e); this.handleChangeDate(); this.handleChangeSelectField();}} 
/>
```

That way all your function calls are in a single function